# Jquery Live click function doesn't work

Tags: jquery, click, live

I have got a problem with Jquery live function. I am adding data dynamically so I have to use live function in order to get clicked a element which added dynamically.

```
$("a.pm_member").live("click", function(){
    alert('clicked');
});
```

Data is added correctly. There are no error messages but it doesn't display alert window.

I will be glad if anyone could help me out with this problem.

**Edit:**

I would like to give more details.

This is what I use in the page;

```
<script>
new TINY.editor.edit('editor',{
    id:'tiny_input',
    height:200,
    cssclass:'te',
    controlclass:'tecontrol',
    rowclass:'teheader',
    dividerclass:'tedivider',
    controls:['bold','italic','underline','strikethrough','|','subscript','superscript','|',
              'orderedlist','unorderedlist','|','outdent','indent','|','leftalign',
              'centeralign','rightalign','blockjustify','|','unformat','|','undo','redo','n','image','hr','link','unlink','|','cut','copy','paste','print','|','font','size','style'],
    footer:false,
    fonts:['Arial','Verdana','Georgia','Trebuchet MS'],
    xhtml:true,
    cssfile:'style.css',
    bodyid:'editor',
    footerclass:'tefooter',
    toggle:{text:'source',activetext:'wysiwyg',cssclass:'toggler'},
    resize:{cssclass:'resize'}
});

$('button#post').click(function () {
    editor.post();
});

$('#suggestions').hide();

function hideSuggestions () {
    $('#suggestions').hide();
}

$("a.pm_member").live("click", function(){
    alert('clicked');
});
</script>
```

This is a PM system. When admin writes a username in receiver input area, script is suggesting some usernames.

```
<input type="text" name="userName" class="medium" maxlength="100" onkeyup="findMember(this.value);" onblur="hideSuggestions();" onfocus="findMember(this.value);"/>
<div id="suggestions"></div>
```

There are more than 1 page included in index.php. I can use .live() function without any problem in any other page but not in send-pm.php.

I am quite confused how to debug it and how to solve it.

.bind(), .live(), .find() it just doesn't work.

Following elements are dynamically added;

```
<div class="flat_area grid_8 searchresults">
<h2 class="box_head grad_colour round_top">Member Suggestions</h2>
<div class="block">
<ul class="full_width">
<li>
<strong>Username: </strong> <a href="#" id="{$found->id}" class="pm_member">{$found->username}</a><br />
<strong>Full Name: </strong> {$found->fullName}<br /> 
<strong>Email: </strong>{$email}
</li>
<li>Total <strong>{$totalRecords}</strong> records found.</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Any ideas how to debug it?

**EDIT 2:**

I even tried to add following code between  element just right after adding jquery and jquery ui files.

```
<!-- Load JQuery -->        
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- Load JQuery UI -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/js/jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.pm_member").live("click", function(){
        alert('clicked');
    });
});
</script>
```

If this would be about some Jquery code braking it, shouldn't that fix it (I am not that good with Jquery though).

**EDIT 3:**

My function to find members

```
function findMember (inputString) {
    if(inputString.length == 0) {
      $('#suggestions').fadeOut(); // Hide the suggestions box
   } else {
      $.get(siteUrl + "includes/ajax/profile.php?do=find-member", {username: ""+inputString+""}, function(data) { // Do an AJAX call
         $('#suggestions').fadeIn(); // Show the suggestions box
         $('#suggestions').html(data); // Fill the suggestions box
      });
   }
 }
```

Once again, thank you for your help and concern.

Comment: Can you post a jsFiddle? We need more details in order to answer your question. From the code you've posted, it looks like it should work.

Comment: what is the HTML that gets generated that is expected to trigger the click event?.

Comment: @where is this code in your page , if something breaks before this , these bindings might not have been attached

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have `click` handlers on *any* ancestors of your `"a.pm_member"` element that do `return false;` or `event.stopPropagation()`, it will kill `.live()`.

This is because `.live()` relies entirely on *event delegation*.

This means that only those events that successfully bubble from the element clicked, up to the `document`, can be analyzed by `.live()` and potentially invoked.

If the event is halted by some ancestor, the `.live()` handler will never see the event.

---

**EDIT:**

*This is an example of an ancestor with a handler assigned that prevents bubbling.*

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/aBtDJ/

*Removing the handler that blocked the bubbling causes the `.live()` handler to work once again.*

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/aBtDJ/1/

---

**EDIT:**

The specific issue is that there's an inline `onblur="hideSuggestions()"` on the `<input>` element just before your `#suggestions` element.

This appears to be used to remove the dialog when you click anywhere. As such, the `blur` event occurs before the `click`, so it never registers.

There isn't a perfect solution for this problem. No matter what, the `blur` is going to happen before the click.

One possibility would be to use the `mousedown` event, which should happen before the `blur`. Of course, this isn't a full click, but it may be good enough.

I'd personally use `.delegate()` instead of `.live()`, but either would work. Here's a `.delegate()` example:

```
$('#suggestions').delegate('a.pm_member', 'mousedown', function() {
    // your code
});
```

Another possibility is to assign your code to that same input element before the `suggestions` element. Of course this would trigger *anywhere* you click, so it may not be what you want.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the explanation. The problem is I have nothing that brakes the element.

Comment: @Pixeler: You're saying that there are no other click handlers attached to any of the elements from which `a.pm_member` descends? They could be inline `onclick="someFunc()"` attributes, or code assigned by another script. If there's nothing like that, you'll need to provide more information in your question.

Comment: @Pixeler: Does it work if you get rid of `TINY.editor.edit...`? Start removing code, testing as you go along,  until all you have left is the `.live()` code. Also, even if there's a lot, posting more of the HTML and JavaScript may help. There's nothing I see there that would cause an issue.

Comment: Didn't help Patrick. This is pretty much it (in send-pm.php), there are tons of other html & JS codes in the page. I have no idea how to show it considering it is an admin panel and language is not English.

Comment: @Pixeler: What is the closest ancestor to `"a.pm_member"` that is *not* dynamically added to the page.

Comment: I uploaded here to test http://www.viphesap.net/localhost.htm, it is just html though and if you type anything in input which is under Alıcı text, it will not work (need to log in) but you could see what is there at least. Thanks a lot for your patience.

Comment: @Pixeler: Where would `pm_member` be if it was on the page? When I do `$('div').live('click',function(){console.log('clicked');});` it works fine. Make sure that the `pm_member` is arriving on the page correctly with the correct class name.

Comment: it is added in #suggestions div correctly (. I added my function to find members. Results : http://img225.imageshack.us/img225/2619/classu.jpg

Comment: When I do `$('#suggestions').append('<a class="pm_member">click me</a>');`, and the click on the appended item, the `live()` handler fires just fine. EDIT: I see you added an image. I'll have a look.

Comment: Removed the protection. You can try to write "ph", "si" and see it in action. Thanks Patrick.

Comment: @Pixeler: The culprit is the inline `onblur="hideSuggestions()"` handler on  the `<input>` element just before `#suggestions`. I just went through and looped all the `input` elements, destroying their `onblur` properties. Once removed, your `.live()` handler works. I'll provide a solution in my answer in a few minutes.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Patrick. I tried many combinations and it just didn't work. Funny thing is I copied and pasted this code from another page (where I was finding members from specific group) and the same code just didn't work on that page. You saved my night. Now I can sleep like a baby. Thank you very much once again.

Answer (score 0):

try using bind() instead of live(),
if this doesn't work I will suggest using find()

example 
if parentClass is a parent class of anchor with class pm_member

use this

```
  $(".parentClass")find("a.pm_member").live("click", function(){
     alert('clicked');
   });
```

for reference on find()--> http://api.jquery.com/find/
for reference on bind() --> http://api.jquery.com/bind/

Comment: Thank you but both didn't help.

Comment: Just a note... chaining is not supported on the .live syntax.  See this topic:  http://api.jquery.com/live/  and search for "Chaining methods is not supported".